# Triggering a python script when charger is plugged in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python, battery

I want to write a python script that will alarm the user when the battery is fully charged in his/her laptop. I can write a python script that will check the battery status every 5 minutes and when the battery is 100% charged, it will fire some alarm. But I don't want this script to be running in the background forever. Instead, I want to run this script only when the charger is plugged in. How do I access this kind of event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell for this task.

```
$battery = get-wmiobject -class win32_battery -erroraction silentlycontinue; while($true){{if($battery){switch($battery){ 6 {& "Python script path"}}}}
```

Now save the code in a ps1 script and replace "Python script path" with the script path. Now run it. Unfortunately, I could not find the Event ID for charger plug-in event.